# @Html.RenderPartialAsync() vs <partial> tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

It looks like Razor Pages have added a new `<partial>` helper tag for including partial views. So I'm wondering why the scaffolding built by Visual Studio doesn't use it. It uses `Html.RenderPartialAsync()` instead.

Does anyone know what the differences are between the two, and what considerations one might make when picking one?

Comment: At present, the Scaffolding is designed to use Html.RenderPartialAsync() method, if you want to use the `<partial>` tag helper, after scaffolding, you could change it the `Html.RenderPartialAsync()` to the `<partial>` tag. Besides, I suggest you could post a new feature request (About use the '<partial>' tag helper when use the scaffolding) on the [scaffolding forums](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues), might be in the next version of Scaffolding, it will use the tag helper.

Answer (score 0):

The [scaffolder code](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding) that works isn't updated to use Tag Helpers. TH (Tag Helpers) are generally preferred over HTML Helpers that provide the same features. See [Tag Helpers compared to HTML Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#tag-helpers-compared-to-html-helpers)